# how to access Symfony's data / business layer from 3rd party apps

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I have te following architectural scenario which doesn't depend on me and I can't change:

[image: architecture]

On one server/machine has several `php` applications and a `postgres`database: each application uses its own schema in order to separate applications'data logically. I'm developing a new application - the one represented by the **A** - using Symfony, which manages and stores data that should be partially accessible by other apps, especially by an old app that's not been developed with symfony nor any other framework. To make it simple you could imagine A app storing movies sent from clients by means of its REST API. I would like **B**, and **C** accessing movies' data: **B** ocasionally should need accessing all the movies with a certain actor acting in it, and **C** would like to update the owner studio (or vice versa). Of course it would be an **A**'s job, the symfony app that was born exactly for that purpose. SO I thought I have two ways, represented by the arrows:

1. **A**'s exposes some way an API that **B** can call. That way I don't have to duplicate business logic and data persistence. Maybe by exposing Doctrine's entities or a controller in some way. Of course I should load at least doctrine, the container, the configuration the httpframework component and when it comes to using **C** I guess this solution would be unfeasible because I would have two apps using and loading most of the same classes, without any kind of isolation between the two. Another (extreme?) solution I thought is not using Symfony for exposing my **A** functionalities to the other apps: I could write an `API` class that connects to the DB and does some logic without any Symfony's support (PDO and friends. No services, no components, nothing.). Luckily what I have to expose is little and that wouldn't be that big problem.
   Finally, I would avoid calling **A**  by means of the shell (i.e. `app.php console/getMovie`) because it consumes tons of resources and I don't think it's that fast. My server is really small and couldn't live up to that
2. **B** and the other apps could access **A**'s schema, but that way I maybe should duplicate some business logic and I see it kind of messy. Maybe **C** app could simply uses an **A** bundle I could write, explicitly written to expose some **A**'s functionalities 3rd party apps need.

These are the two solutions I've found, but I do appreciate how you think I should design this.

Comment: Having trouble understanding your actual question.  It sound like A should expose a RESTlike api for B and C to consume.  All B&C needs is the php curl functions.  But then you start going off into a place where I am having trouble following.

Comment: I don't want to expose some functionalities by means of REST: imagine an user accessing B's functionalities: if I need to access A from B, that means I should open a REST request towards A: two applications running for a single request looks like a lot of resources! For that reason I was trying to access A programmatically, by loading the bare necessities

Comment: plus: the functionalities I want to expose for the other applications running on the server should be reachable just the applications themselves and not exposed to the users. Do you still think that I should opt for the REST way, exposing some REST only for local requests?

Comment: All I can say is that without an api you end up with all your apps being dependent on each other.  Not easy to maintain.  Very doubtful that performance will be an issue for local requests.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to share data between schema by using views in a common place (usually public schema).

This has several advantages:

- it lets you use your schema structure the way you want.
- it exposes the data you want.
- it lets you manage the write accesses you want (yes, views may be writeable)
- it makes you able to deal with GRANT/REVOKE easily.
- it makes the applications able to leverage Postgres` LISTEN/NOTIFY feature to communicate.

There are downsides:

Updating a view means deploying new model files on all the applications using it. It can be a project on its own that the other applications depend on through composer.